# Problem returning a value from clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set links on a page like this

```
<a href='' class='contact' data-index='1'>One</a>
<a href='' class='contact' data-index='2'>One</a>
<a href='' class='contact' data-index='3'>One</a>
```

I am trying to return the value of the data-index of each link when it is clicked but Whenever I click on each link, the data-index of the first link is always returned because jQuery will select all the links with class = 'contact' on the page. 
I am trying to figure out how to select the data-index of the clicked link.

I use something like this :

```
var m_data = $("a#contact").attr("data-index");
```

I've also tried something like this :

```
$("a#contact").click(function() {
  var data = $(this).data('index');
});
```

but data was undefined.

Please how do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#` is an id selector. Which should be unique. When using id-selector in jQuery, it will always return the first element, since it isn't expecting to find any more items.

Change your code

```
<a data-index="1" class="contact">Whatever</a>

$("a.contact").click(function() {
    var data = $(this).data("index");
});
```

And as Eskat0n mentions, since jQuery 1.6, jQuery automatically gets `data-` attributes via the `data()` method

Comment: This is the correct answer, but probably worth noting that the OP will have to use the second method outlined in the question (with `this` rather than reusing the selector).

Answer (score 4):

Since jQuery 1.6.x values of data attributes populates into data associated with element by jQuery, so if your html look like `<a class="contact" data-index="5"></a>` your code should work:

```
$("a.contact").click(function() {
  var data = $(this).data('index');
  // data is "5"
});
```

As you can see there is correction: `#` used to get element by id which needed to be unique. Use class intead of id for multiply link elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a.contact").each(function()
{
    $(this).click(function()
    {
        var data = $(this).attr('data-index');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You want [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/).  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YJJr7/) indicates how it can be used if the list of links is the only list on the page and also if there are other DOM elements mixed in with the links.

Comment: +1 That's actually a good point, if the OP is after a way to get the index of the link in a container, this is probably a lot easier (: